# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in WeatherUnderground response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax request to WeatherUnderground service the following way:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=' + $input.val(),
    type: 'GET',
    dataType : "JSONP",
    success : function(parsed_json) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(parsed_json);
        alert(typeof parsed_json);
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.RESULTS.length; i++) {
            suggestions[i] = obj.RESULTS[i].name;
        }
    },
    error : function(parsed_json){
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

But when I get the responce back I see the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

And the first line of the responce is underlined

```
{ "RESULTS": [
    {
        "name": "Dakar, Senegal", 
        "type": "city", 
        "c": "SN",
        "zmw": "00000.1.61641",
        "tz": "Africa/Dakar",
        "tzs": "GMT",
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.1.61641",
        "ll": "14.730000 -17.500000",
        "lat": "14.730000",
        "lon": "-17.500000"
    }, ...
```

What might cause this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the value of `$input.val()`?

Comment: Anything I enter in the text box. In this particular example it was just letter d.

Answer (score 0):

you are using JSONP means JSONP (JSON with Padding) it is different than json.
Please refer this link for more details.
link: http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/index.html

The only change on the Client side with JSONP is to add a callback parameter to the URL. The simplest way to do this is to add 'callback=?' in which case jQuery will generate a unique function name and pass that to the server.

On the Server you need to get the 'callback' parameter and, instead of returning the raw JSON, you wrap that string in a function definition, like this "()". You don't need to know the function name in advance - you just get it from that callback parameter.

You should also set the content type to 'application/javascript', although this doesn't appear to matter in my tests.

Back on the client side you treat the returned function just like the raw JSON object.

```
`var url = host_prefix + '/jsonp?callback=?';
```

`$.getJSON(url, function(jsonp){
    $("#jsonp-response").html(JSON.stringify(jsonp, null, 2));
  });`

This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

also possibly worth noting is that in the case of the wunderground API they provide a callback parameter so you can avoid ajax altogether in the following manner...

```
<body>
<input id="inp"/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Go!">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#btn").on("click",getDeets);

function getDeets(){
var str=$("#inp").val();
if(document.getElementById("myscr")){
document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("myscr"));
}
var scr=document.createElement("script");
scr.id="myscr";
document.getElementById("myscr").src="http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query="+str+"&cb=myfunc";
document.body.appendChild(scr);
}

function myfunc(o){
console.log(o);
}
</script>
</body>
```